# Debian 8 - Setup Preferences for installing php7.0

Tags: linux, apt, debian-jessie, php7, preferences

Please help setup preferences for installing php7.0 and relative packages (some of it not a stable release).

I have OS Debian 8.

I setup sources lists for packages in `etc\apt\sources.list.d\`:

**`security.list`**

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates  main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
```

**`stable.list`**

```
deb     http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
```

**`testing.list`**

```
deb     http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
```

**`unstable.list`**

```
deb     http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
```

I setup some preference files for packages in `etc\apt\preferences.d\`:

**`security.pref`**

```
Package: *
Pin: release l=Debian-Security
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

**`stable.pref`**

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 900
```

**`testing.pref`**

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 750
```

**`unstable.pref`**

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 50
```

I created file **`99default-release`** in `etc\apt\apt.conf.d\` with content:

```
APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

And finally when i run command for installation php7.0 i have next error:

```
root@machie:/etc# apt-get install php7.0

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.0 but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.0-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.0-cgi but it is not going to be installed
W: No priority (or zero) specified for pin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

P.S. Without sources, preferences and apt.conf file php7.0 installed success form "`deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all`" repo. But i hope it is possible setup preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just delete `http://packages.dotdeb.org` repo from sources.list. Now i can install testing release from debian repo by executing command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f -y -t testing php7.0 php7.0-curl php7.0-cli php7.0-gd php7.0-xml php7.0-mbstring php-xdebug
```

with all dependence (apache2 etc.)

For update testing packages run command:

```
apt-get install `apt-show-versions -u -b | grep testing`
```

For downgrade to stable release any package, create file in `etc\apt\preferences.d\` with next content:

```
Package: <package_name_here> 
Pin: release a=testing
Priority: 1001
```

and run `apt-get update`